# Not able to build using npm for Superset after changing constant.js file

Tags: javascript, npm-install, apache-superset

I was trying to build after changing the constant.js to change the timeout duration, but I was not able to build it.

I tried npm install but it failed:

> npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/gulp-sourcemaps/-/gulp-sourcemaps-1.7.0.tgz npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with status code 404 npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/gulp-sourcemaps/-/gulp-sourcemaps-1.7.0.tgz npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with status code 404 npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/gulp-sourcemaps/-/gulp-sourcemaps-1.7.0.tgz

link from package.json: https://gist.github.com/amit641/5ebd20a949c105c76c18eafd7c9809f6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using npm to build the project we can use **yarn**. Following is the link where I found the solution:

https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/pull/3120

Comment: Hello, unfortunately the link is broken , can you provide the document or a new link?